# How to delete multiple rows in datagridview and database using vb.net window forms

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I have a data gridview which loads with these codes:

```
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = <SQL> SELECT UserName,Activity,CDate as `Date` FROM tbl_activity </SQL>.Value

    Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable

    grdActivity.Columns.Add(colCB)
    myadap.Fill(mydt)
    grdActivity.DataSource = mydt
    myadap.Dispose()
```

And i have my delete button with these codes:

```
Dim selected As Integer
    selected = grdActivity.SelectedRows.Count
    If grdActivity.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        'you may want to add a confirmation message, and if the user confirms delete
        For a As Integer = 0 To selected
            myr.Close()
            mycom.Connection = cn
            mycom.CommandText = "Delete from tbl_activity where ID = '" & a & "' "
            mycom.ExecuteReader()
            myr.Close()
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Select 1 row before you hit Delete")
    End If
```

Can anyone help me with the right codes so i can delete databases bounded rows not only in my datagridview but also directly from the database.. thanks..

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid SQL injection and other problems.  Is 0,1,2,3... really the IDs you are always deleting?  That's what your code says.  You probably want the id to come from the rows you are reading.  You probably want to use ExecuteNonQuery instead of that ExecuteReader — you aren't reading anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't dispose of the DataAdapter, you can use it to update the database. If you configure myadap with the appropriate INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands your button click code becomes nothing more than error handling and:

```
myadapt.Update(mydt)
```

Don't read data out of the grid, let the grid manipulate the data it is bound to and the DataAdapter will handle the rest.
I have a complete example (for MS SQL server) [here](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/)